# Need a working example to query NFTs and display them (is it even possible?)

Tags: nft

Does anyone know of or is willing to share their code on how to obtain all NFTs on a tz.. wallet (mainnet) and display them?

I can't find a single working example, I can find lots of applications of past which no longer work and documentation on api's and libraries long gone but nothing that actually works. Typescript client side.

I am a full stack dev but I'm not that clued up on blockchain work.

Thanks

Comment: kukai, temple, Airgap and Umami are all open source wallets on Tezos that display NFTs. They are all on github / gitlab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very simple example of fetching and displaying account's NFTs with Vue.js. It's not production-ready, but just for demonstration purposes.

https://jsbin.com/faqupezoga/1/edit?html,output.
Specify your address in the input and it will show your NFTs. Click "Load more" to load more NFTs.

```
<html>
<div id="app">
    <span>Enter your address: </span>
    <input v-model="address">

    <h4>NFTs of<br>{{ address }}</h4>

    <div v-for="nft in nfts" :key="nft.id">
        <h3>{{ nft.balance }} x {{ nft.name }}</h3>
        <a :href="nft.artifactUri" target="_blank">
            <img height="200" :src="nft.displayUri" />
        </a>
    </div>

    <button type="button" @click="fetch" style="margin-top:2rem">
        Load more
    </button>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<script>
    const App = {
        data: () => ({
            address: 'tz1fRdhaTLTVfvftwY2RvSNuKnCbHLXT85Wu',
            nfts: [],
        }),
        async mounted() {
            // initial fetch
            await this.fetch();
        },
        watch: {
            address() {
                // if account has been changed, reset and refetch NFTs for the new one
                this.nfts = [];
                this.fetch();
            },
        },
        methods: {
            async fetch() {
                // fetch NFTs from TzKT API
                const res = await fetch(`https://api.tzkt.io/v1/tokens/balances`
                    + `?account=${this.address}&balance.ne=0&token.metadata.displayUri.null=false&offset=${this.nfts.length}&limit=2`
                    + `&select=id,balance,token.metadata.name as name,token.metadata.displayUri as displayUri,token.metadata.artifactUri as artifactUri`);
                // process IPFS links
                const items = (await res.json()).map(x => ({
                    ...x,
                    displayUri: this.ipfsLink(x.displayUri),
                    artifactUri: this.ipfsLink(x.artifactUri),
                }));
                // save the NFTs
                this.nfts = this.nfts.concat(items);
            },
            ipfsLink(uri) {
                return uri.replace('ipfs://', 'https://cloudflare-ipfs.com/ipfs/');
            },
        },
    };
    Vue.createApp(App).mount('#app');
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped greatly. :)